# How to set the selectedRange of Kendo UI Editor to highlight excess characters like Twitter?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I'm trying to wrap with a span parts of the nodes of a Kendo UI Editor that contains characters that exceed the character limit set. I'm trying to achieve what Twitter does when you type in your tweets; the excess characters are highlighted in red.

How do I change the selectedRange of the Kendo UI Editor to select only those that exceed the character limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Traverse the DOM tree of the editor via its `body` field.
2. Find longer words.
3. Surround longer words with a span using the DOM Range API.

Here is a naive implementation which only works for immediate children of the BODY element:

```
function ellipsis(editor, node) {
  // traverse child nodes
  for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = node.childNodes[i];
    // check only text nodes (nodeType == 3)
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
      // get the text of the node
      var text = child.nodeValue;

      // naive split to words
      var words = text.split(" ");
      var position = 0;

      // traverse the words
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];

        // check word length
        if (word.length > 4) {
          var range = editor.createRange();

          // position the range over the word
          range.setStart(child, position + 1);
          range.setEnd(child, position + 1 + word.length);

          // create a span that will wrap the word              
          var span = editor.document.createElement("span");
          span.style.display = "inline-block";
          span.style.width = "50px";
          span.style.overflow = "hidden";
          span.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
          span.style.verticalAlign = "bottom";
          span.style.textOverflow = "ellipsis";
          span.title = word;

          // wrap the word
          range.surroundContents(span);
          child = span.nextSibling;
          position = 1;
        } else {
            position += word.length;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/EcIL

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was to set the selected text of the editor and then just call the exec('backColor', false, 'blue') to highlight the text that exceeds the character limit.